# Pattern recognition: one class only

Tags: algorithm, math, machine-learning, pattern-recognition

I've got a question: how can I do pattern recognition,  if I have only one class?
In other words, I want get answer from algorithm is it my pattern, or not, i. e. 1 or 0.

At first sight,  it is a simple two classes classification, but in this case arise problem: what is class, that describe 0 class (how we can describe complement to universum?)
If set A - set, that contains objects with some property,  then not A (U\A, where U is universum) - set of objects,  without this property.

I can get examples this task in particularly:
Face recognition (it is face of person, or not)
Recognition some thing on the picture.
In this case in one piece training set I must specify pictures with person face (or some thing), but what must contain another piece training set? I can't specify all pictures, that will not contain this thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is simple [classification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_classification) problem, the question is "Is it an item from the set?" and the question has a boolean answer: true or false.

In the example of face recognition - you are actually looking for face detection. This can be done, for example using [viola-jones object detection framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viola%E2%80%93Jones_object_detection_framework).

The idea is to provide items that are in the set (faces), and some randomly chosen items that are not in the set. and classify them with the boolean classifier.